# How to create tally counts by group in long format using dplyr

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, grouping

I would like to generate long format tables of counts from a dataframe organised by groups defined by columns in R. I'd like something that replicates .groupby in pandas. I'm sure dplyr can do it but I can't find the right syntax for exactly what I want.

```
# Test data
Samples <- c('A01', 'A02', 'A03', 'A04', 'A05', 'A06', 'A07', 'A08', 'A09', 'A10', 'A11', 'A12', 'A13', 'A14', 'A15', 'A16', 'A17', 'A18', 'A19', 'A20')
Group <- c(1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 1, 2)
Country <- c('Thailand', 'Vietnam', 'Cambodia', 'Vietnam', 'Cambodia', 'Thailand', 'Laos', 'Vietnam', 'Vietnam', 'Vietnam', 'Laos', 'Cambodia', 'Vietnam', 'Cambodia', 'Cambodia', 'Laos', 'Laos', 'Cambodia', 'Cambodia', 'Vietnam')
Year <- c(2012, 2018, 2012, 2018, 2018, 2012, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2012, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2012, 2012, 2018, 2018, 2012, 2018, 2012)
df = data.frame(Samples, Group, Country, Year, row.names=c(1))
df
```

And I'd like to create outputs like these, grouping by 'Group' with counts for each country or year:

```
# Desired output 1 - country counts
Group_name <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3)
Countries_bygroup <- c('Cambodia', 'Laos', 'Thailand', 'Vietnam', 'Cambodia', 'Laos', 'Vietnam', 'Cambodia', 'Thailand')
Country_counts <- c(3, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1, 4, 3, 1)   
group_by_country = data.frame(Group_name, Countries_bygroup, Country_counts)
group_by_country

# Desired output 2 - Year counts
Group_name2 <- c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3)
Years_bygroup <- c(2012, 2018, 2012, 2018, 2012)
Year_counts <- c(3, 7, 1, 5, 4)
group_by_year = data.frame(Group_name2, Years_bygroup, Year_counts)
group_by_year
```

The end result is I want to make plots like these:

```
# Plot by country
library('ggplot2')
plot <- ggplot(group_by_country, aes(x = Group_name, y = Country_counts, fill = Countries_bygroup)) + 
  geom_bar(position = "fill",stat = "identity") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = percent_format()) +
  xlab("Sample group") +
  ylab("")
plot
```

[image: Example plot]

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use the `count` function from the `dplyr`. No need to `group_by` the columns as the `count` function can automatically take care of the grouping. Just put the columns you want to count to the function.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% count(Group, Country)
# # A tibble: 9 x 3
#   Group Country      n
#   <dbl> <fct>    <int>
# 1     1 Cambodia     3
# 2     1 Laos         3
# 3     1 Thailand     1
# 4     1 Vietnam      3
# 5     2 Cambodia     1
# 6     2 Laos         1
# 7     2 Vietnam      4
# 8     3 Cambodia     3
# 9     3 Thailand     1

df %>% count(Group, Year)
# # A tibble: 5 x 3
#   Group  Year     n
#   <dbl> <dbl> <int>
# 1     1  2012     3
# 2     1  2018     7
# 3     2  2012     1
# 4     2  2018     5
# 5     3  2012     4
```

Comment: I get an error: "Error: wt_var must be a single variable"

Comment: Not sure what is `wt_var`. Please make sure my code works for your example data frame, and then try to figure out what is the difference between your example data frame and your real-world data frame.

Comment: I get that message using the example data

Comment: @WillHamilton But I didn't. Re-start your R console to see if that helps.

Comment: Try using `dplyr::count`. My guess is that you've got another function named `count` that's masking `dplyr`'s version

Comment: Yep that works great, thanks both:
data_counts <- df %>% dplyr::count(Group, Country)
And then plotting using data_counts.
Weird, I don't know what other function I have that could be named count...